# How to configure hostname based ssl certificate on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku

I bought a SSL certificate through https://dnsimple.com/ for Heroku and got an email telling me: "To use it, please create CNAMEs for any hostnames you wish access via SSL, pointing them to: SSL_URL"

I would like https://www.mydomain.com to work. Until know I had three A aliases for mydomain.com pointing to the three heroku addresses (simply following this: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)
And one CNAME doing www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com

I'm not sure on how to configure that (see doc http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#id24).
I have created a CNAME of www.mydomain.com pointing to the SSL_URL but it doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Heroku was having problem with their previous extension, the new 'ssl endpoint' add-on simply fixed that problem. Simply follow the tutorial.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Heroku SSL add-on.

They will provide the CNAME value for you.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain_ssl_wwwyourdomaincom

Comment: I have done all of this :) I got the CNAME, my domain is hosted at OVH, so I have created a cname pointing to that given SSL DNS. But it doesn't change anything.